# ListView/GridView and narrator WPF

Tags: wpf, class, listview, gridview, narrator

I have a question to following issue:

I have a ListView that includes a GridView.

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,10,48" Name="listView_Anlagen" AutomationProperties.LabeledBy="{Binding Dateiname}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dateiname" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dateiname}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dateigröße" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dateigroesse}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Pfad" Width="460" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pfad}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The 3 bindings are defined in a class.

```
    public class Anlage
{
    public string Pfad { get; set; }
    public string Dateiname { get; set; }
    public string Dateigroesse { get; set; }
}
```

Every item of this class gets merged in a list.

```
        internal static List<Anlage> AnlagenListe = new List<Anlage>();
```

And this list is the source for the ListView.

My issue is: When I tab into the list and select an item, the narrator is reading "namespace.name_of_the_class", not its content or just one property.

My question is: how to get the narrator to read one specific property instead?

EDIT: I currently found a dirty workaround by overriding the "ToString" method of the class.

```
    public class Anlage
{
    public string Pfad { get; set; }
    public string Dateiname { get; set; }
    public string Dateigroesse { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Dateiname;
    }
```